# How to make .NET Reflection enumerate a class that is never actively used

Tags: c#, reflection

Let us have a simple class library (ClassLibrary1)

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    // a simple class

    public class Class1
    {

        // some methods...

        public void foo() { }

        public void bar() { }
    }
}
```

and a simple console application that keeps a reference to the library:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            foreach (var assembly in assemblies) Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName.Split(' ')[0]);

        }
    }
}
```

When run, ConsoleAppliacation1 produces the following output:

```
mscorlib,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities,
System.Windows.Forms,
System,
System.Drawing,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime,
vshost32,
System.Core,
System.Xml.Linq,
System.Data.DataSetExtensions,
Microsoft.CSharp,
System.Data,
System.Net.Http,
System.Xml,
mscorlib.resources,
ConsoleApplication1,
```

As you can see, there is no ClassLibrary1 entry in the assemblies... but if I modify the ConsoleApplication1 to look like this (note the additional line declaring var x):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // let us know about the assembly...
            var x = new ClassLibrary1.Class1();

            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            foreach (var assembly in assemblies) Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName.Split(' ')[0]);       
        }
    }
}
```

then it does appear (see last line)...

```
mscorlib,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities,
System.Windows.Forms,
System,
System.Drawing,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync,
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime,
vshost32,
System.Core,
System.Xml.Linq,
System.Data.DataSetExtensions,
Microsoft.CSharp,
System.Data,
System.Net.Http,
System.Xml,
mscorlib.resources,
ConsoleApplication1,
ClassLibrary1,
```

This is a problem for me, because I actually need to enumerate all assemblies, even those that are never directly used, in order to automatically populate a list of classes defined in ClassLibrary1 via reflection.

either my google-fu isn't working, or my question isn't trivial...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`?

Comment: If they aren't referenced, you need to enumerate the assemblies in the bin directory and load them manually.

Comment: @Will: the library is referenced. Or at least... I mean I added a project reference to it in the console application project. I suspect the compiler is optimizing something and not including the class in the final binary unless I actually "reference" it from the code. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Leo128 it seems like, `GetReferencedAssemblies` will also only get the assemblies that are loaded in memory, if you haven't used to compiler might be clever enough to remove that reference for performance reasons.

Comment: You both pointed me to a new direction, because I understood that my approach was faulty at a much more general level. In order to do what I wanted to do, I will actually need to use the assembly (I need to have the consumer call a registration function stating both a namespace AND the assembly to scan for classes), even through I won't actually spawn any instances of its classes. I will elaborate a detailed explanation and post it as soon as I get my code sample working, which I hope will happen very soon. Thank You so much for the moment

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead, as the [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) will only get the assemblies that are currently loaded in the `AppDomain` of process:

```
 // Display information about the EXE assembly.
 Assembly a = typeof(Program).Assembly;
 foreach (AssemblyName an in a.GetReferencedAssemblies() )
 {

 }
```

for details see the [MSDN documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: uhm... it only lists mscorlib, but I still need to "touch" Class1 by instantiating it in order to get it in the output.

Comment: i replied to your comment above, it's quite possible that the compiler optimizes the build and removes the unused assembly references.

Comment: try adding the using statement for it's namespace and see what happens

Comment: I tried, nothing changes. besides, visual studio notices the namespace is never used even at design time. It's improbable that it survives a rebuild

Comment: so add a using statement didn't worked, if yes, then it might be because compiler might be removing extra namespaces at build time as they were used no where in code, but i am not sure, need to test that